# is there any way add line number beside each DOM tags?

Tags: php, dom

My code is like this which will access all the DOM elements. Now i want to add line   number    beside them. can anyone please help. thanks.

```
<?php   
$dom = new domDocument;
// load the html into the object
$dom->loadHTMLFile('$url');
// keep white space
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
// nicely format output
$dom->formatOutput   = true;
//get element by tag name
$htmlRootElement = $dom->getElementsByTagName('html');
$new = htmlspecialchars($dom->saveHTML(), ENT_QUOTES);
echo '<pre>' .$new. '</pre>';
?>
```

The code above would not out put give any line number. i want to do something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
1.<html>
2.<head>
3.    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
4.   <title></title>
5.</head>
6.<body>
7.</html>
```

Any suggestion please. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split the string by new lines, and print out the line number followed by the line:

```
$lines = preg_split( '/\r\n|\r|\n/', $new );//split the string on new lines
echo "<pre>";
foreach($lines as $lineNumber=>$line){
  echo "\r\n" . $lineNumber . ". " . $line; 
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $html);
```

There's my hint, I'm sure you can figure the rest out.
There are already PHP libs for this btw, like [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/)

Oh, and your code has a small error.
Where you're loading the HTML, you do `'$url'`, which literally means `$url`, not whatever your variable it. Use double-quotes or none at all.

Comment: thanks. $url there i meant for example, 'http://www.google.com' instead of the address i wrote $url thought it would make more sense.